# Sample weighting didn't help in imbalanced data training

Tags: keras, imbalanced-data

I am training a two-layer LSTM network with 16 through 32 cells in each layer and had a fairly imbalanced dataset for training. Based on my seven class frequencies, the sample weights calculated through the simple formula of total_samples/class_frequency is [3.7, 5.6, 26.4, 3.2, 191.6, 8.4, 13.2], and I add this weight for each sample to the tuple of (data, label) output of my dataset generator to run my Keras `model.fit()` function. The training code was:

```
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
mc = ModelCheckpoint(model_file, monitor='val_acc', mode='max', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', mode='max', verbose=1, patience=50)
history = model.fit(train_data, epochs=epochs, steps_per_epoch = train_steps, validation_data=val_data,
                            validation_steps = val_steps, verbose=verbose, callbacks=[es, mc])
```

Then I used the best saved model to evaluate it and calculate performance statistics by this code (my data is in tensorflow datasets):

```
saved_model = load_model(model_file)
iterator = test_data.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()
y_test = y_pred = np.empty(0)
for i in range(test_steps):
    batch = sess.run(next_element)
    x_test_batch = batch[0]
    y_test_batch = batch[1]
    y_pred_batch = saved_model.predict_on_batch(x_test_batch)
    y_test = np.append(y_test, np.argmax(y_test_batch, axis=1))
    y_pred = np.append(y_pred, np.argmax(y_pred_batch, axis=1))
print('\nTest data classification report:\n{}\n'.format(classification_report(y_test, y_pred)))
```

But what I see in the output statistics is that the weighted stats are overall worse than unweighted ones (setting all weights equally to 1), even for rare classes (highest weights). Here is the stat:

For weighted run:

```
     class     prec.     recall    f1       support
     0.0       1.00      0.97      0.98     79785
     1.0       0.89      0.88      0.88     52614
     2.0       0.61      0.76      0.68     11090
     3.0       0.96      0.93      0.95     91160
     4.0       0.59      0.92      0.72      1530
     5.0       0.89      0.90      0.89     34746
     6.0       0.81      0.87      0.84     22289

accuracy                           0.92    293214
macro avg      0.82      0.89      0.85    293214
```

For unweighted run:

```
     class     prec.     recall    f1       support
     0.0       0.99      0.98      0.99     79785
     1.0       0.89      0.90      0.90     52614
     2.0       0.79      0.66      0.72     11090
     3.0       0.95      0.96      0.95     91160
     4.0       0.85      0.82      0.83      1530
     5.0       0.89      0.92      0.90     34746
     6.0       0.88      0.86      0.87     22289

accuracy                           0.93    293214
macro avg      0.89      0.87      0.88    293214
```

what is wrong here?

Comment: It would be more helpful to know what loss function you used and the code block of your fit function

Comment: I updated my post and added the code sections.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `class_weight` in `fit` function or `fit_generator` to apply weights to your classes.

First you have to create a dictionary with `label:weight` format:

```
class_weight = {0: 3.7,
            1: 5.6,
            2: 2.64,...}
```

Then apply it to your fit function:

```
history = model.fit(train_data, epochs=epochs, steps_per_epoch = train_steps, validation_data=val_data, 
                        class_weight=class_weight, validation_steps = val_steps, verbose=verbose, callbacks=[es, mc])
```

If you want to apply a weight per instance, then you need to create an array that contains the weight for the corresponding instance in the training data and set it in `sample_weight` in fit function.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, I added the weights per sample to my dataset generator function. According to Tensorflow documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model) it is well supported and should not have any problem.